# i have error in my code error while Insert and Fetch Images From Mysql Database in PHP (pls this is not duplicate quetion)

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I am unfortunately getting this error.Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\work\index.php on line 41.Any idea what it means please? Still on the learning curve of php sorry....
here is my code with databse testing table name tbl_image.

```
<?php $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");  if(isset($_POST["insert"])) {  
  $file = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));  
  $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_images(name) VALUES ('$file')";  
  if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))  
  {  
       echo '<script>alert("Image Inserted into Database")</script>';  
  }}?>  


<!DOCTYPE html><html>  
  <head>  
       <title>Webslesson Tutorial | Insert and Display Images From Mysql Database in PHP</title>  
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
       <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
  </head>  
  <body>  
       <br /><br />  
       <div class="container" style="width:500px;">  
            <h3 align="center">Insert and Display Images From Mysql Database in PHP</h3>  
            <br />  
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
                 <input type="file" name="image" id="image" />  
                 <br />  
                 <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="Insert" class="btn btn-info" />  
            </form>  
            <br />  
            <br />  
            <table class="table table-bordered">  
                 <tr>  
                      <th>Image</th>  
                 </tr>  
            <?php  
            $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_images ORDER BY id DESC";  
            $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query); 
                $start = 1;
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
            {  
                 echo '  
                      <tr>  
                           <td>  
                                <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['name'] ).'" height="200" width="200" class="img-thumnail" />  
                           </td>  
                      </tr>  
                 ';  
            }  
            ?>  
            </table>  
       </div>  
  </body></html><script>$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('#insert').click(function(){  
       var image_name = $('#image').val();  
       if(image_name == '')  
       {  
            alert("Please Select Image");  
            return false;  
       }  
       else  
       {  
            var extension = $('#image').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();  
            if(jQuery.inArray(extension, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg']) == -1)  
            {  
                 alert('Invalid Image File');  
                 $('#image').val('');  
                 return false;  
            }  
       }  
  });});</script>
```

Comment: **pls anybody help me i want serious help**

Comment: nobody knows what is your problem. you should ask your database to tell you that

Comment: how to do that brother